# Installing Styx to Pull Prometheus Data

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

Anyone out there install Styx to pull Prometheus data? I can get to the Styx link on Githib, but I am not seeing how to install it?

Any advice is appeciated.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I'm new to the go language and did not realize I had to do a "go build". That shoud be part of the readme. Thanks!